# Mapping an open set to a closed one

Tags: calculus

Construct an example of a continuous function $f:(0,2) \to \mathbb R$ which maps the open set $(0,2)$ onto a closed set. ( This shouldn't be very difficult but I'm not quite sure how to draw it out)

Comment: What is the simplest function you can think of?

Comment: Try $x \mapsto \sin (\pi x)$ for something more varied...

Comment: A constant function.

Answer (score 1):

Define $f : (0, 2) \to \mathbb R$ by  $f(x) = 0$.

Notice that $\operatorname{im}(f) = \{0\}$ is a closed set in $\mathbb R$ (since $\mathbb R \setminus \{0\} = (-\infty, 0) \cup (0, \infty)$)

---

Or maybe you could translate $(0, 2)$ into $(-\pi/2, \pi/ 2)$ and then choose $f = \tan$.

In this case $\operatorname{im}(f) = \mathbb R$ which is closed.

---

Or perhaps $f(x) = \sin (\pi x)$.

In this case $\operatorname{im}(f) = [-1, 1]$ which is closed.